# Whether my model follows the QQ plot and DHARMa residual in glmmTMB?

Tags: diagnostic, glmmtmb

I ran this code and found the result. Could you please help me to figure out my model follows DHARMa residual?

```r
model1<-glmmTMB(ctmax ~ lat+ (1|site), dispformula=~lat,data=data)
summary(model1)
```

Got this result:

[image]

Comment: We can't really do much without a reproducible example (i.e., being able to see your data). `DHARMa` is certainly reporting problems (all that red text), but it's hard to say more (are these problems ignorable? Is there anything you can do to fix them?) without more information.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information.